# Android, TCP, Servlet -- To and Fro communication without external libraries. What are the standard efficient ways to do it?

Tags: javascript, java, android, sockets, servlets

**What I am trying to build here looks something like this.**

```
MyClients(Multiple) <------> Server(Me) <------> TheirClients(multiple, live)
```

- **MyClient1** (HTML)

  **Through Server (HTML -> Servlet -> Android)**

  - HisClient1 (uses `Android` app)(monitored live by MyClient1)
  - HisClient2 (uses `Android` app)(monitored live by MyClient1)
  - **...**
- **...**

**The flow:** (Can have multiple `MyClients` and `HisClints` online at the same time)

- MyClient comes online.
- Timely pinging HisClients get connected to the Server.
- MyClient gets notified.
- MyClient sends request to HisClient through server.
- HisClient replies through Server.
- MyClient is updated.

On the `HisClient` end i.e. `Android`, I'm running `TCP Socket()` to timely ping the server and stay alive. Cannot use `URLConnection` as the client have to stay alive all the time if the server requests something. Also I don't want to use any external library, so `GCM` is not an option.

On the `MyClient` side, I first tried using `PHP` but it is inefficient of handling **multiple live** clients. Then, after some searching I came to know that `Servlets`  are good in such cases. So I started developing a `Servlet`.

**Now the questions are:**

Am I going in the right direction? I mean is there anything better for such a scenario? If yes, **what and how**? I mean what are the APIs and how will it maintain the live traffic?

If no, how do you handle multiple live `HisClients` with `Servlet`? I know, here multiple is not a problem but how to keep them **live** and keep updating `MyClient`?

Comment: you can use java servlets you can use c# web sockets, I would suggest c# web sockets as they are more modern and much cleaner

Comment: What are the C# APIs and how can it maintain the live  traffic?

Comment: you can have a look at this for starters http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp

Comment: Yes that is how will I implement Socket but what about multiple clients and keeping them live?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "keeping them alive" ?

Comment: Alive means constantly listen to them. Like with a while(true) loop in case to TCP  Socket.

Comment: Well do that then? keep the socket connection open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105083/discussion-between-ryan-and-bhargav).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you going to spend so much time reinventing the wheel?  Maintaining 100 connections with a web socket isn't hard.  Maintaining 1,000,000 will be impossible.  If you need an event system, use something like [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) or [Pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com) to distribute events.  Sure, you'll add a couple of Kbytes or MBytes to your app.  But how will you know you can scale your solution?

Maintaining any kind of a connection will be just waiting for a scalability nightmare.  Make things a bit less tightly coupled and you'll be much better off.

Comment: I'm developing this just to learn. I think scalability requires optimized code and big data farms. Atleast by developing such a thing by myself will teach me code optimization. That's the basic reason i don't want to use any external ready to use solutions.